# bluetooth disconnected just after connected on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bluetooth, ubuntu-20.04, bluetooth-gatt

i'm trying to make my own photobooth using instant photo printer which uses bluetooth and dye sublimation type. For doing that, BT connection needs to be implemented in the python or node js code. Basically, i'm planing just utilize the system command.
for now, however, having tested Polaroid Hi-print and Kodak P300R, but none of these are not even connected. in specifically, it disconnected by remote user(device) just after connected.(Actually, they only supports for mobile platforms like android or iOS)

now even I'm confusing it's possible. Could you guys help me to get through with?

Here's are the btmon logs of connection using "hcitool cc [btaddr]" ..

```
@ RAW Open: hcitool (privileged) version 2.22              {0x0002} 3407.844746
@ RAW Close: hcitool                                       {0x0002} 3407.844761
@ RAW Open: hcitool (privileged) version 2.22       {0x0002} [hci0] 3407.844771
< HCI Command: Create Connection (0x01|0x0005) plen 13  #196 [hci0] 3407.844787
    Address: 00:15:83:41:DB:94 (IVT corporation)
    Packet type: 0xcc18
      DM1 may be used
      DH1 may be used
      DM3 may be used
      DH3 may be used
      DM5 may be used
      DH5 may be used
    Page scan repetition mode: R2 (0x02)
    Page scan mode: Mandatory (0x00)
    Clock offset: 0x0000
    Role switch: Allow slave (0x01)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4               #197 [hci0] 3407.982359
  Create Connection (0x01|0x0005) ncmd 2
    Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Role Change (0x12) plen 8                  #198 [hci0] 3408.627344
    Status: Success (0x00)
    Address: 00:15:83:41:DB:94 (IVT corporation)
    Role: Slave (0x01)
> HCI Event: Connect Complete (0x03) plen 11            #199 [hci0] 3408.633340
    Status: Success (0x00)
    Handle: 3
    Address: 00:15:83:41:DB:94 (IVT corporation)
    Link type: ACL (0x01)
    Encryption: Disabled (0x00)
@ RAW Close: hcitool                                {0x0002} [hci0] 3408.633412
< HCI Command: Read Remote Supp.. (0x01|0x001b) plen 2  #200 [hci0] 3408.633427
    Handle: 3
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4               #201 [hci0] 3408.637320
  Read Remote Supported Features (0x01|0x001b) ncmd 2
    Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Max Slots Change (0x1b) plen 3             #202 [hci0] 3408.638316
    Handle: 3
    Max slots: 5
> HCI Event: Max Slots Change (0x1b) plen 3             #203 [hci0] 3408.644343
    Handle: 3
    Max slots: 5
> HCI Event: Read Remote Supported Fe.. (0x0b) plen 11  #204 [hci0] 3408.646313
    Status: Success (0x00)
    Handle: 3
    Features: 0xff 0xff 0xc9 0xfa 0x83 0xa7 0x79 0x87
      3 slot packets
      5 slot packets
      Encryption
      Slot offset
      Timing accuracy
      Role switch
      Hold mode
      Sniff mode
      Park state
      Power control requests
      Channel quality driven data rate (CQDDR)
      SCO link
      HV2 packets
      HV3 packets
      u-law log synchronous data
      A-law log synchronous data
      CVSD synchronous data
      Transparent synchronous data
      Flow control lag (most significant bit)
      Broadcast Encryption
      Enhanced Data Rate ACL 2 Mbps mode
      Enhanced inquiry scan
      Interlaced inquiry scan
      Interlaced page scan
      RSSI with inquiry results
      Extended SCO link (EV3 packets)
      EV4 packets
      EV5 packets
      3-slot Enhanced Data Rate ACL packets
      5-slot Enhanced Data Rate ACL packets
      Sniff subrating
      Pause encryption
      Enhanced Data Rate eSCO 2 Mbps mode
      3-slot Enhanced Data Rate eSCO packets
      Extended Inquiry Response
      Secure Simple Pairing
      Encapsulated PDU
      Erroneous Data Reporting
      Non-flushable Packet Boundary Flag
      Link Supervision Timeout Changed Event
      Inquiry TX Power Level
      Enhanced Power Control
      Extended features
< HCI Command: Read Remote Exte.. (0x01|0x001c) plen 3  #205 [hci0] 3408.646327
    Handle: 3
    Page: 1
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4               #206 [hci0] 3408.647314
  Read Remote Extended Features (0x01|0x001c) ncmd 2
    Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Read Remote Extended Fea.. (0x23) plen 13  #207 [hci0] 3408.678320
    Status: Success (0x00)
    Handle: 3
    Page: 1/1
    Features: 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
      Secure Simple Pairing (Host Support)
< HCI Command: Remote Name Req.. (0x01|0x0019) plen 10  #208 [hci0] 3408.678378
    Address: 00:15:83:41:DB:94 (IVT corporation)
    Page scan repetition mode: R2 (0x02)
    Page scan mode: Mandatory (0x00)
    Clock offset: 0x0000
< ACL Data TX: Handle 3 flags 0x00 dlen 10              #209 [hci0] 3408.678386
  L2CAP: Information Request (0x0a) ident 1 len 2
    Type: Extended features supported (0x0002)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4               #210 [hci0] 3408.680339
  Remote Name Request (0x01|0x0019) ncmd 2
    Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5  #211 [hci0] 3408.706320
    Num handles: 1
    Handle: 3
    Count: 1
> ACL Data RX: Handle 3 flags 0x02 dlen 16              #212 [hci0] 3408.708440
  L2CAP: Information Response (0x0b) ident 1 len 8
    Type: Extended features supported (0x0002)
    Result: Success (0x0000)
    Features: 0x00000080
      Fixed Channels
< ACL Data TX: Handle 3 flags 0x00 dlen 10              #213 [hci0] 3408.708483
  L2CAP: Information Request (0x0a) ident 2 len 2
    Type: Fixed channels supported (0x0003)
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5  #214 [hci0] 3408.712315
    Num handles: 1
    Handle: 3
    Count: 1
> ACL Data RX: Handle 3 flags 0x02 dlen 20              #215 [hci0] 3408.714439
  L2CAP: Information Response (0x0b) ident 2 len 12
    Type: Fixed channels supported (0x0003)
    Result: Success (0x0000)
    Channels: 0x0000000000000002
      L2CAP Signaling (BR/EDR)
> HCI Event: Remote Name Req Complete (0x07) plen 255   #216 [hci0] 3408.733311
    Status: Success (0x00)
    Address: 00:15:83:41:DB:94 (IVT corporation)
    Name: Hi-Print 2×3 - DB94
@ MGMT Event: Device Connected (0x000b) plen 35     {0x0003} [hci0] 3408.733351
    BR/EDR Address: 00:15:83:41:DB:94 (IVT corporation)
    Flags: 0x00000000
    Data length: 22
    Name (complete): Hi-Print 2×3 - DB94
@ MGMT Event: Device Connected (0x000b) plen 35     {0x0001} [hci0] 3408.733351
    BR/EDR Address: 00:15:83:41:DB:94 (IVT corporation)
    Flags: 0x00000000
    Data length: 22
    Name (complete): Hi-Print 2×3 - DB94
< HCI Command: Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) plen 3          #217 [hci0] 3410.692257
    Handle: 3
    Reason: Remote User Terminated Connection (0x13)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4               #218 [hci0] 3410.693261
  Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) ncmd 2
    Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Disconnect Complete (0x05) plen 4          #219 [hci0] 3410.790256
    Status: Success (0x00)
    Handle: 3
    Reason: Connection Terminated By Local Host (0x16)
@ MGMT Event: Device Disconnected (0x000c) plen 8   {0x0003} [hci0] 3410.790295
    BR/EDR Address: 00:15:83:41:DB:94 (IVT corporation)
    Reason: Connection terminated by local host (0x02)
@ MGMT Event: Device Disconnected (0x000c) plen 8   {0x0001} [hci0] 3410.790295
    BR/EDR Address: 00:15:83:41:DB:94 (IVT corporation)
    Reason: Connection terminated by local host (0x02)
```

Comment: `Remote User Terminated Connection (0x13)` error message often means that the two ends of the link haven't found a profile/service that is defined on both ends of the link. This is likely to be that you don't have the correct thing running on you ubuntu machine. You will need to find what UUIDs is being advertised by the printer and then look to support that on your machine. FYI:  `hcitool` has been [deprecated](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617) and you should use `bluetoothctl`.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the device (previously paired) and remove from the list.

Then do fresh connection it will work.